# Is there a way to select rows based on a loose distinct?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with a lot of replicated rows, and I want to make a dataset with no replications. Date and time are the main ways of distinguishing between distinct and similar rows, but sometimes the times are a bit off. I want to reduce my dataset so that if 2 rows are within 1 hour of each other on the same day the second instance does not show up.

```
input_date<-c("4/20/2014", "5/15/2002", "3/12/2019", "3/12/2019", "3/12/2019", "3/12/2019")
input_time<-c("4:30", "4:30", "9:00", "9:55", "12:00", "12:00")
input<-cbind(input_date, input_time)
colnames(input)<-c("date", "time")

#use distinct to remove duplicate values--this removes final row, but I want it to also remove row 4. 

output<-distinct(input, date, time)
```

Is there any easy way to tell R to get rid of rows with values that are close to each other but not exactly the same?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that rounds times to make groups based on the hour.

Then, use {dplyr} `group_by` / `slice` to get the first row of each group.

```r
input_date <- c("4/20/2014", "5/15/2002", "3/12/2019", "3/12/2019", "3/12/2019", "3/12/2019")
input_time <- c("4:30", "4:30", "9:00", "9:55", "12:00", "12:00")

# make a data.frame
input <- data.frame(date =input_date, time = input_time)

# use dplyr for data manipulation of groups
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# take the 1st slice index from each group
input %>% 
  mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s %s", date, time),   
                               format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"),
         hour = round(datetime, "hours")) %>%
  group_by(hour) %>%
  slice(1)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#> # Groups:   hour [5]
#>   date      time  datetime            hour               
#>   <chr>     <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>             
#> 1 5/15/2002 4:30  2002-05-15 04:30:00 2002-05-15 05:00:00
#> 2 4/20/2014 4:30  2014-04-20 04:30:00 2014-04-20 05:00:00
#> 3 3/12/2019 9:00  2019-03-12 09:00:00 2019-03-12 09:00:00
#> 4 3/12/2019 9:55  2019-03-12 09:55:00 2019-03-12 10:00:00
#> 5 3/12/2019 12:00 2019-03-12 12:00:00 2019-03-12 12:00:00
```